# Linking data to date

Tags: r, date, csv

I'm trying to calculate capital per worker (k) using r.
We are using real data and so instead of t I'm using date based on a .csv file.
date has been correctly loaded as

```
> date[1]
[1] "2009/07/01"

> date[3]
[1] "2011/07/01"
```

However this part in particular doesn't appear to work for me

```
for (date in 2:7){
y[date] <- k[date-1]^alpha
k[date] <- (1-delta-n[date])*k[date-1]+s*y[date]
}
```

Full code here:

````
```{r}
labour <- read_csv("LF.csv")
date <- labour$date
# Defining parameters
alpha <- .4 #After several hours discussion with Pardy
n <- labour$growth
delta <- 0.041
g <- 0.016
s <- 0.274
k <- rep(NA, 7)
y <- rep(NA, 7)
kappa <- (s/(n[1] + delta))^(1/(1-alpha))
k[1] <- kappa
y[1] <- k[1]^alpha
for (date in 2:7){
y[date] <- k[date-1]^alpha
k[date] <- (1-delta-n[date])*k[date-1]+s*y[date]
}
data.frame(date = date[1:7], k ) %>% melt(id = "date") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable,group = 1)) +
geom_line() +
ylim(0, 18)
```
````

Comment: do you mean `for (eachdate in date[2:7])`? Right now, each date you are using in that loop is just 2,3,4,5,6 or 7

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I'm trying to use date[1],date[2] etc instead of t to link k and y to [date]

Comment: you should use a new name for that loop variable - it is overwriting your vector `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your code, here is the most obvious to me.

You should include some data (ie paste in the output of `dput(head(labour))`), and an expected output so it is easier to troubleshoot the rest.

You are using `date` as your loop variable, but also have a variable named date that gets changed by it:

```
date <- c("2009/07/01", "2009/07/03", "2011/07/05")
date

for (date in 2:3){
  print(date)
}

date
```

Recall that loop variables are globally assigned, unlike internal function variables. You should rename that loop variable.